# It wont render my website and its template to localhost1313

Tags: html, terminal, hugo

(Hugo)
I'm receiving this in the terminal when I attempt to run the LocalHost server:

```
Veers-MacBook:FullFork veergala$ hugo server
Building sites … WARN 2020/09/11 09:15:11 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "home": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
WARN 2020/09/11 09:15:11 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "taxonomyTerm": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
WARN 2020/09/11 09:15:11 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "taxonomyTerm": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.

                   | EN  
-------------------+-----
  Pages            |  3  
  Paginator pages  |  0  
  Non-page files   |  0  
  Static files     |  0  
  Processed images |  0  
  Aliases          |  0  
  Sitemaps         |  1  
  Cleaned          |  0  

Built in 33 ms
Watching for changes in /Users/avinashgala/FullFork/{archetypes,content,data,layouts,static}
Watching for config changes in /Users/avinashgala/FullFork/config.toml
Environment: "development"
Serving pages from memory
Running in Fast Render Mode. For full rebuilds on change: hugo server --disableFastRender
Web Server is available at http://localhost:1313/ (bind address 127.0.0.1)
Press Ctrl+C to stop
WARN 2020/09/11 09:15:32 found no layout file for "HTML" for kind "home": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
```

I am new to Hugo/Terminal and I have no idea what to do.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Each of your page has a "`Kind`": see "[Page Kinds](https://gohugo.io/templates/section-templates/#page-kinds)"

Hugo looks for a layout in order to render your site:
See "[Hugo's Lookup Order](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/)"

If you don't have your own layout folder, with those `_default` layout pages, you can add [declare a theme](https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/theme-components/)

> The name used in the theme definition above must match a folder in `/your-site/themes`, e.g. `/your-site/themes/my-shortcodes`.

See "[A Beginner’s Guide to Creating a Static Website with Hugo](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/a-beginner-s-guide-to-creating-a-static-website-with-hugo/read/1)" by [Ilya Bodrov](http://bodrovis.tech/) as an example.

Don't forget to do:

```
hugo server -D
```

> The `-D` option means that drafts should also be displayed on the website.
>
> By default, all content is created in draft mode, so we have to provide this option for now.
> This command will display brief statistics about your site and start the server with live reloading enabled. Live reloading simply means that whenever you modify the code, the web page will reload automatically in the browser.